# Qt (c++)でWindowsとLinuxを認識するマクロ

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

LinuxとWindowsで動作するアプリをQt上で作成しています
同じソースをLinuxとWindowsでそれぞれビルドしているのですが
ビルドする際にWindowsかLinuxかを判定するようなマクロはないでしょうか

LinuxとWindowsで動作を変えたいのですが
マクロで切り替えたいのですが探しきれませんでした

Windows側はMinGW64bitを使用しています

Answer (score 4, accepted):

kunifさんの回答にある、コンパイラの判別方法の他に、Qtで定義されているプラットフォーム別のマクロがあります。

https://wiki.qt.io/Get_OS_name
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html

`#ifdef Q_OS_WIN` や `#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX` を使うと良いです。

Answer (score 1):

この記事が参考になるでしょう。定義済みマクロで識別出来るとあります。
[How can I detect g++ and MinGW in C++ preprocessor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17493759/9014308)
解決済み回答では無いこちらの方が詳細かと。

> For GCC:
>
> ```
> #ifdef __GNUC__
> ```
>
> For MinGW:
>
> ```
> #ifdef __MINGW32__
> ```
>
> x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc defines both `__MINGW32__` and `__MINGW64__`.

そして解決済み回答のコメントに最新の情報がSourceForgeに載っているとあります。
[Pre-defined Compiler Macros](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/)
[Compilers](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/)

> **MinGW and MinGW-w64**
> MinGW (formerly known as MinGW32) is a toolchain for creating 32 Bit Windows executables. The MinGW-w64 projects offers toolchains for creating 32 Bit and 64 Bit Windows executables. The following table shows which macros are defined by each toolchain:
>
> ```
> Type           Macro                   Description MinGW32 MinGW-w64 32Bit MinGW-w64 64Bit
> Identification __MINGW32__                         defined defined         defined
> Version        __MINGW32_MAJOR_VERSION Version     defined defined         defined
> Version        __MINGW32_MINOR_VERSION Revision    defined defined         defined
> Identification __MINGW64__                         -       -               defined
> Version        __MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR Version     -       defined         defined
> Version        __MINGW64_VERSION_MINOR Revision    -       defined         defined
> ```
>
> Notice that `__MINGW32_MAJOR_VERSION`, `__MINGW32_MINOR_VERSION`, `__MINGW64_VERSION_MAJOR`, and `__MINGW64_VERSION_MINOR` are only defined if appropriate headers are included. Appropriate headers are `<stdlib.h>`, `<stdio.h>`, `<windows.h>`, `<windef.h>`, and probably more.